# Format of REST incoming data: POST fields or JSON?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest

In most examples I saw the incoming data (for example for creating new entity) data is POST'ed as form encoded. This is great for 'flat' objects, but I need to transfer more complex objects (2-3 levels of nesting). Is it acceptable to transfer them in the body of POST request as JSON-encoded string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you set the proper header to `application/json` and generally use the HTTP mechanisms of content negotiation: yes, this is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

[json](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) and [form-data](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) are media types. Pick what you want and be sure to set the [content-type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) to the one you've chosen.

Answer (score 0):

I believe JSON is commonly used to communicate arrays within the body of a document. I am using it here to transfer this array of mapped points and associated attributes http://ageara.com/test/map-service.php?action=listpoints ... albeit not with REST style ;-)

Comment: The question is about JSON in the body of a *request*.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. Yes looks like JSON is acceptable as POST request as long as you define the payload with the media type. According to the man who wrote the book on [REST](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven).